# Why Insomnia started to not recognize Cyrillic words?

Tags: postman, insomnia

I use Insomnia as a REST client. But it started to not show Cyrillic words properly. Below you can see how it shows them: [image]

English words are ok. It used to work with Cyrillic words perfectly. I don't know what went wrong since. May be I changed some of the settings. So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: And Postman doesn't show them? have you tried it in Postman?

Comment: Postman shows. Insomnia doesn't.

Comment: Use Postman then - it's the best! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in 6.0.1 and a fix will be included in the next release. https://github.com/getinsomnia/insomnia/issues/1088